# How to use RGB colors to plot

Tags: matlab, colors, matlab-figure

I was searching a lot before I made this question. I tried several ways, spent hours with it, but I couldn't solve this simple problem. You should know, that I'm a beginner in Matlab.

These datas are x and y locations, measured by an RFID reader, I would like to plot them with different colours. I used 8 RFID tags during the measurement, so I have 8 fix points - these are marked with '*', hence I would like to use 8 (RGB) colours instead of the 7 basic colours. I wrote this in Matlab and it works properly, but just with the 7 basic colours, so 2 data sets have the same colour.

```
close all
clc
RealPOSX=[40 31 0 -31 -40 -32 0 +31];RealPosY=[0 27 40 27 0 -27 -40 -27]
RealTagID=['A3 ' ;'A1 ' ; '9F '  ;'9D ' ; '9B ' ; 'A9 '  ; 'A7 ' ; 'A5 ' ];

for i=1:length(XLocalization)
temp=Epc{i};
ID(i,:)=temp(end-2:end);

end

colorsR=['b*'; 'g*'; 'r*' ;'k*' ;'c*'; 'y*' ;'m*' ;'k*']
colorsR2=['bo'; 'go'; 'ro' ;'ko' ;'co'; 'yo' ;'mo' ;'ko']
for i =1: length(RealPOSX)
    idx = all(ismember(ID,RealTagID(i,:)),2)
    pos=find(idx==1);
    POS{i}=pos;

plot(RealPOSX(i),RealPosY(i),colorsR(i,:))
hold on
plot(XLocalization(POS{i}),Ylocalization(POS{i}),colorsR2(i,:))

end

grid on
```

The easiest way seemed to me just to change the color type like that - this was the first, what I have tried:

```
colorsR=['[0 0 0]*'; '[0 1 0]*'; '[1 0 0]*' ;'[0 0 0]*' ;'[0 1 1]*'; '[1 1 0]*' ;'[1 0 1]*' ;'[0.5 0.5 0]*']
colorsR=['[0 0 0]o'; '[0 1 0]o'; '[1 0 0]o' ;'[0 0 0]o' ;'[0 1 1]o'; '[1 1 0]o' ;'[1 0 1]o' ;'[0.5 0.5 0]o']
```

But of course it didn't work.

---

**Edit**:

I changed the codes now like @Wolfie suggested.

It looks like this now:

[image: Figure 2].

The new code:

```
close all
clc
RealPOSX=[40 31 0 -31 -40 -32 0 +31];
RealPosY=[0 27 40 27 0 -27 -40 -27];
RealTagID=['A3 ' ,'A1 ' , '9F '  ,'9D ' , '9B ' , 'A9 '  , 'A7 ' , 'A5 ' ];

for i=1:length(XLocalization)    
    ID(i,:)=Epc{i}(end-2:end);    
end

colorsR = {[0 0 0], [0 1 0], [1 0 0], [0 0.5 0.5], [0 1 1], [1 1 0], [1 0 1], [0.5 0.5 0]};

for i =1: length(RealPOSX)

    pos = find(ismember(RealTagID,'AA'));
    % WHAT IS THIS 'AA'? 

    hold on   

    plot(RealPOSX(i),RealPosY(i), 'Color', colorsR{i}, 'Marker', '*') % It's working properly
    plot(XLocalization(pos),Ylocalization(pos), 'Color', colorsR{i}, 'Marker', 'o')

    hold off

end

grid on
```

And here are my variables. I hope you can reach it. [My variables](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tfr9vnmiwuoleke/Test%203%20-%20Height-100cm%2C%20Disabled%20Antennas%20-%20%2C%20TxPowerInDbm-23.25%2C%20UpdateIntervalSeconds-5%2C%20ComputeWindowSeconds-10%2C%20ReaderMode_AutoSetDenseReader%2C%20TagAgeIntervalSeconds-20%2C%20tags%2040%20cm%20from%20origo%20.txt?dl=0)

Comment: I think the syntax you are looking for is is `plot(x,y,'*','Color',[r,g,b])`.

Comment: Something similar, but I would like to use different colours for the different x and y coordinates. It works like that ( thx @Wolfie ):

`colorsR = {[0 0 0], [0 1 0], [1 0 0], [0 0.5 0.5], [0 1 1], [1 1 0], [1 0 1], [0.5 0.5 0]};

plot(x, y, 'Color', colorsR{i}, 'Marker', '*' )     `

Comment: You have `k*` in there twice. Is that the problem?

Comment: Yes but finally I figured ut.
THX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what all your variables are so I don't know if this will fix everything but here's a code breakdown:

Comments explain changes

```
% Remember to end lines with ";" to suppress outputs
RealPOSX=[40  31   0  -31  -40  -32    0   31];
RealPosY=[ 0  27  40   27    0  -27  -40  -27];

% Doing this:
% RealTagID=['A3 ' ;'A1 ' ; '9F '  ;'9D ' ; '9B ' ; 'A9 '  ; 'A7 ' ; 'A5 ' ];
% is not the best way to store strings.
% Instead, use a cell to keep strings separate and make indexing easier
RealTagID={'A3', 'A1', '9F', '9D', '9B', 'A9', 'A7', 'A5'};

for i = 1:length(XLocalization)

    % Depending on what is stored in Epc, you may not need temp.
    % It would be more concise to do ID{i}=Epc{i}(end-2:end);
    temp = Epc{i};
    ID{i}=temp(end-2:end);

end

% Same note as above about cells
colorsR ={'b*', 'g*', 'r*', 'k*', 'c*', 'y*', 'm*', 'k*'};
colorsR2={'bo', 'go', 'ro', 'ko', 'co', 'yo', 'mo', 'ko'};

for i =1:length(RealPOSX)

    %idx = all(ismember(ID,RealTagID(i,:)),2)
    %pos=find(idx==1);
    %POS{i}=pos;

    %You can get pos more simply:
    pos = find(ismember(RealTagID,ID{i}));
    %POS{i} = pos
    % But you're using POS{i} immediately so why store it at all?

    % you should just hold on around your plotting, and hold off after
    hold on
    plot(RealPOSX(i), RealPosY(i), colorsR{i})
    plot(XLocalization(pos), Ylocalization(pos), colorsR2{i})
    hold off

end

grid on
```

As for actually plotting with RGB colours, you should use this in your loop:

```
colorsR = {[0 0 0], [0 1 0], [1 0 0], [0 0 0], [0 1 1], [1 1 0], [1 0 1], [0.5 0.5 0]};
plot(XValues, YValues, 'Color', colorsR{i}, 'Marker', '*')
```

Comment: Actually I changed everything, how you wrote down. It's better, now I have 8 different colours for the 8 different real locations of the tags. But the measured datas don't represent properly. It connects the dots with a line and do not depict all of the datas. 
It looks like that: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/69ry219py0bqqwy/trying.jpg?dl=0)

I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: I can't see dropbox links, try adding the image as an edit to your question.

Comment: I couldn't write down my now programm, so I uploaded this as well on Dropbox: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ndk9xlwph0n3z1g/trying.txt?dl=0)

And here are my variables: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tfr9vnmiwuoleke/Test%203%20-%20Height-100cm%2C%20Disabled%20Antennas%20-%20%2C%20TxPowerInDbm-23.25%2C%20UpdateIntervalSeconds-5%2C%20ComputeWindowSeconds-10%2C%20ReaderMode_AutoSetDenseReader%2C%20TagAgeIntervalSeconds-20%2C%20tags%2040%20cm%20from%20origo%20.txt?dl=0)

Comment: I changed the question.

Comment: I have changed my answer, I forgot to change the `'AA'` after my testing, it should be `ID`. Also you need to change `RealTagID` to be a cell like in my code, note the curly braces and no spaces.

Comment: Thank you very much, now it's working. But I used scatter instead of plot. 

Like that:

 `for i =1: length(RealPOSX)
 % pos = find(ismember(RealTagID,ID));
   

  idx = all(ismember(ID,RealTagID(i,:)),2)
    pos=find(idx==1);
    POS{i}=pos;


% plot(RealPOSX(i),RealPosY(i), 'Color', colorsR{i}, 'Marker', '*') 
scatter(RealPOSX(i),RealPosY(i),50,colorsR{i},'*')

 hold on  
%plot(RealPOSX(i),RealPosY(i),colorsR{i})
% plot(XLocalization(pos),Ylocalization(pos), 'Color', colorsR{i}, 'Marker', 'o')
scatter(XLocalization(pos),Ylocalization(pos),50,colorsR{i}) `